# shell command meaning and htaccess file?

Tags: linux, apache, shell

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5
```

this command is in a file called `php.fcgi`. i don't know what's the meaning.

```
AddHandler php-fastcgi .php
Action php-fastcgi /cgi-bin/php.fcgi
```

the above command in in the `.htaccess` file, what's the meaning of them. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line defines that the file is to be executed by command `/bin/sh` which is Unix shell.
Next line, shell command `exec` is an argument, executes it and replaces the current shell with that process (i.e the shell script will stop at that point).

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5
```

Together this means that it is a shell-script wrapper to execute PHP5 binary.

In the .htaccess the first line defines a handler named `php-fastcgi` for all files ending in .php:

```
AddHandler php-fastcgi .php
```

Second line defines that the handler `php-fastcgi` can be found at the location `/cgi-bin/php.fcgi`:

```
Action php-fastcgi /cgi-bin/php.fcgi
```

Note that this is not filesystem location, but URL path, which is further parsed by Apache to find actual filesystem location (ScriptAliases, Aliases, etc).

All of this together means that `.php` files are executed with above shell script, which in turn runs PHP5 binary.